# what is the value of $c_n?$

Tags: real-analysis

**Rudin Theorem** $7.26 $:
If $f$ is a continuous complex function on $[a, b]$, there exists a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P_n(x) = f(x) $$
uniformly on $[a, b]$. If $f$ is real, the $P_n$ may be taken real.

In the theorem of the proof it is written that

> We put
> $$\tag{47}  Q_n(x) = c_n \left( 1- x^2 \right)^n \qquad (n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots), $$
> where $c_n$ is chosen so that
> $$ \tag{48} \int_{-1}^1 Q_n(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = 1 \qquad (n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots). $$

Here  Im  not getting the value of $c_n ?$

what is the value of $c_n?$

**My thinking** :If the choice  of $c_n$ is  $\int_{-1}^1 Q_n(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = 1$, then $c_n=1$

Comment: $c_n$ is just $\frac{1}{\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n \, dx}$. What this is exactly doesn't really matter.

Comment: Bit more details: $$
1 = \int_{ - 1}^1 {Q_n (x)dx}  = \int_{ - 1}^1 {c_n (1 - x^2 )^n dx}  = c_n \int_{ - 1}^1 {(1 - x^2 )^n dx}  \Rightarrow c_n  = \frac{1}{{\int_{ - 1}^1 {(1 - x^2 )^n dx} }}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$ \int_{-1}^1 Q_n dx = c_n \underbrace{\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n dx}_{=:I_n}$$

If the integral term $I_n$ on the right was already $1$, then you can simply set $c_n =1$.  But $I_n$ may not be $1$. By choosing $c_n$, we can change the value to anything we like, since $I_n$ is not zero. In particular we may make the choice

$$c_n = \frac1{I_n}=\frac1{\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n dx}.$$

The exact value of $I_n$ is not important. Only the much easier property that $I_n\neq0$. (Though you can with effort or a computer show that $I_n = \sqrt\pi \Gamma(n+1)/\Gamma(n+3/2)$.)

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-1}^{1}Q_n(x)dx=c_n\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)^ndx=c_n*\dfrac{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(\dfrac{3}{2}+n)}=1 \implies c_n = \dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac{3}{2}+n)}{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(n+1)}$

Comment: This is mixed up: as $n\to\infty$, this becomes unbounded, although the integrand approaches $0$ a.e. (except at $x=0$) on $[-1,1]$. I think you meant the reciprocal.